# Error when trying to log into StackExchange Data Explorer

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, login

Yesterday and today I tried to log in to Data Explorer using OpenID. But every time I see this error:

[image: Image of Server Error in '/' Application]

Am I missing something? Or isn't it my fault?

Comment: No repro here, though I do still get logged in differently depending on whether I use the HTTP or HTTPS version of my OpenID.

Comment: @Popular Demand The problem is I can't event enter an URL. The error occurs as soon as I click the OpenID logo.

Comment: The important part of that comment was that I can't repro; I can consistently log in just fine. The other stuff was just a side note.

Comment: Which OpenID provider?

Comment: @Jon Seigel myopenid

Comment: I assume you can still reproduce this. What's your browser info?

Comment: @Jon Seigel I tested it with FF 3.6.15 and Google Chrome 10.0.648.133

Comment: Hmmm... I'm using the same version of FF and it works fine for me (I haven't tried logging in, but I can get to the myopenid login page). Have you tried completely clearing your browser cache? Also, did this start happening recently?

Comment: @Jon Seigel. I tried to clear the browser cache. No improvements. The error occurs since my first try to log in.

Comment: I had this a few weeks ago. I'm on chrome 11 beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed in latest