# Logging into Data Explorer gives ASP.NET Runtime Error

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, login

> Server Error in '/' Application.

The exact text is hidden from me.

To be exact, I logged in using a LiveJournal OpenID.

Comment: Same with myOpenID. Google OpenID works, for some reason.

Comment: I have a repro ... working on a fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well any guesses to what the bug was:

[image: winning]

Fixed now.

Comment: Craaaapppp... please tell me I didn't check that in. I remember touching code near that part of it.

Comment: @Jon ... yeah ... it was your bug :) I prefer the new implementation I checked in anyway - so the end result is we are still winning

Comment: Damn, my bad. I'll be more careful next time.

Comment: Also, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84488/se-data-explorer-crashes-on-login-with-myopenid and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82480/error-when-trying-to-log-into-stackexchange-data-explorer I believe are probably solved by this as well.