# Why am I jon.doe when logging into Data Explorer?

Tags: support, data-explorer, user-accounts, openid

I just tried to login to the Data Explorer and it gave me a jon.doe user.

I used the same openid...

How can I link this to my other accounts?

Comment: That link goes to an Edgar Codd photo now, so this question won't be useful in the future; voting to close.

Comment: I've seen a new Jon.doe user created today. The name is confusing. Even user12345 is better, if you are not able to show real name from openid provider. See feature request http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146382/please-use-a-more-obviously-synthesized-username-for-new-accounts-on-http-data

Comment: This is in the [SEDE FAQ](http://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq) (I now belatedly learned).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it helps if you keep using your same open id provider :) First time you logged in with google, second time with myopenid.

data.se, does not participate in our global auth scheme. It predated it and our stack exchange identity scheme does not have public endpoints.

As it stands data.se tries to guess a login for you from your openid provider, if it fails it assigns you a unique `jon.doe` login.

I went ahead and merged your 2 accounts

Comment: Thanks @waffles. I wasn't sure that the DE wasn't tied into that.

Comment: A pity, then, that SE's own openID does not enable [data.SE] to "guess right".

Comment: How can I/the-next-person merge our accounts?

Comment: @dfc On [my (now deleted) duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233717/data-se-thought-im-jon-doe14939) I was told that these accounts are separate, and that there is no need (or way) to merge.

Comment: Suggest removing the first paragraph from this answer, as this seems to happen regardless.

Answer (score 4):

I think it was side effect of this fix?

[Logging into Data Explorer gives ASP.NET Runtime Error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84316/logging-into-data-explorer-gives-asp-net-runtime-error/84966#84966)

Comment: I experienced that...

Comment: "Invalid endpoint" (or something like that) was another one that created jon.does.

Comment: That bug was an issue with generating the jon.doe names *uniquely* -- the name generation itself is by design. (See @waffles' answer.)