# Wrong user when logging into Data Explorer

Tags: support, openid, data-explorer, user-accounts

I think I'm having the same issue as reported in this question:

[Why am I jon.doe when logging into Data Explorer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85265/why-am-i-jon-doe-when-logging-into-data-explorer)

When I log into SEDE with the same OpenID account I use for SE, a different user comes up ("James Wiseman" on Stack Exchange and "adsense" in Data Explorer).

Is there anything I can do personally to rectify this, or must I rely on the admins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The related question you mention here is a different issue (when creating an account with an OpenID where we can't programmatically determine your name, the account is assigned a unique predefined 'jon.doe' name).

---

Data Explorer's login mechanism is not linked to the Stack Exchange Network, because Data Explorer is open-source and the Network site code is not.

Since it's a totally separate system, you get assigned a separate user account, which cannot be associated like a user account on the Network can be.

If you want your displayed information on Data Explorer to match your other profiles, you have to manually copy in the info.

Comment: So now I have two accounts, one at work and one at home, both with the same OpenID. Is that expected?

Comment: @mmyers: Two accounts on SEDE? No. That sounds like a bug.

Comment: So what does this statement from the SEDE FAQ mean http://data.stackexchange.com/faq 'We will automatically populate any parameter named ##UserId## with your user id on the respective sites (if your EmailHash matches)'?

Comment: @James: That means it searches in the selected site's data for an e-mail hash matching the hash of the user who's currently logged in, and if found, auto-populates a parameter field. It has nothing to do with the login system.

Comment: Right, ok. So how come it doesn't autopopulate for me?

Comment: @mmyers not anymore you don't. (:  SEDE will now account for valid variations on the openid, and I merged your accounts.