# Login problem - a name unknown to me appeared

Tags: support, data-explorer, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I jon.doe when logging into Data Explorer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85265/why-am-i-jon-doe-when-logging-into-data-explorer)

I have tried to login the first time to SE Data Explorer, through the Google account, but I got a new for me name jon.doe7352. Logout and attempt to login again brings me to the same point. It doesn't matter, what google account I use - after every try the system insists that I am jon.doe7352. Could it be somehow repaired?

As for similar question [Wrong user when logging into Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95486/wrong-user-when-logging-into-data-explorer), I *haven't* picked any ID, but now I am recalling, that the page itself, a moment before going to the google page, put something in the ID field. It was too fast to notice what exactly. So, it is a bug?

Comment: What were you expecting to happen instead?

Comment: This question's title is very melodic.

Comment: You can edit your profile and change the name to anything you like.

Comment: Every time I login to any StackExchange server after the SO that was my first I got the same my name and a profile connected to my other SE profiles

Comment: @jadarnel27, thank you, I *had* written some songs :-)

Comment: [Very](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85265/why-am-i-jon-doe-when-logging-into-data-explorer) [related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95486/wrong-user-when-logging-into-data-explorer)

Comment: @AnnaLear But it wouldn't be connected to my other SE profiles

Comment: @jadarnel27 Hmm. I *haven't* picked any ID, but now I am recalling, that the page itself a moment before going to the google page, put something in the ID field. It was too fast to notice what exactly.

Comment: @Gangnus As mentioned in the questions that jardarnel27 linked to, your Data Explorer account is not directly linked to your Stack Exchange account.

Comment: Oh, really. I mislooked it. Pardon. So, I have to delete the question?

Comment: First time that happened to me, I was pretty confused too. Only after I recognized the numeric part of my new identity as a user ID did I try out all my OpenID log-ins until I found the one I used originally. Having the default user name be "jon.doe" is not a very smart move IMO, because I had to [look up what it means](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/John_Doe). I thought I'd hijacked someone's account. The fact that it's misspelled doesn't help, either.

Comment: "I thought I'd hijacked someone's account" Me too! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments by jardarnel27 and Tim Stone, a Data Explorer account is not directly linked to the Stack Exchange account.