# My StackExchange DataExplorer Account doesn't show up in my Accounts!

Tags: support, status-bydesign, data-explorer, user-accounts

I recently got my [StackExchange DataExplorer Account](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/7347/draks). Why doesn't show up on my normal [account](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/19341/draks) under "Accounts"?

Is StackExchange DataExplorer somehow special?

Comment: For what it is worth. It doesn't show for me either. Also, since this is not a question specifically about Math.SE, I'll migrate it to Meta.SO where it'd be more visible to those who knows what's going on.

Comment: This is normal. SEDE is open-source and doesn't have account association. See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85271/131713) and [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95531/131713).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data explorer isn't as tightly integrated into the network as the Q&A sites, StackExchange.com, and Area 51 are.  This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), for a couple reasons.

1. Data Explorer is an [open source project](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/), tight integration with our login system becomes complicated accordingly
2. Unlike the other sites, your activity on data.se isn't *really* likely to be of much interest to other members of the community
3. It'd be a really weird fit display wise, Area 51 is already a bit odd out but Data.SE is really wildly different

Comment: *"...but as soon as we add voting, comments, and flagging to queries, and reputation to voting activity, we'll get right on integrating it with the accounts and flair."* is what you want to say, right?

Comment: @AdamDavis if by "we" you mean "anybody but me", then sure why not.

Comment: @AdamDavis Actually, with regards to the comments...

Comment: Commenting ['cause I wanna know](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122580/170332)... Adding: @AdamDavis