# Does the person get notification if I edit my comment and add @hisname in it?

Tags: discussion, comments, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will edited comments reach addressees?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40989/will-edited-comments-reach-addressees)
>   [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

I sometimes forget to add the *@hisname* in a comment, so I edit and put it there. Will he be notified after my edits?

Comment: Add a comment to [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122577/2915), then edit in the @AdamDavis and I'll let you know if I get a notification for it.

Comment: I did receive the notification, so Chichiray is correct in stating that the user is notified.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, the user will be notified.

Comment: This answer is a bit chatty - can you put in a `tl;dr` ??  :-)

Comment: Just "Yes" is enough as the reply