# Stack Exchange data explorer account creation issue

Tags: support, data-explorer, login

> See also: [My StackExchange DataExplorer Account doesn't show up in my Accounts!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122552/my-stackexchange-dataexplorer-account-doesnt-show-up-in-my-accounts)

I created my account in Data Explorer and used my already registered Google Login for logging.

It created the account and provided it name display `jon.doe10667` while I have created accounts on other Stack Exchange sites which take the display name automatically.

My [StackExchange Data Explorer profile](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/10666/jon-doe10667)
while this has my profile picture **but not my name and not my open id.**
My [StackExchange profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1903805/narendra-pathai)

What should I do? I am scared! Even the site does not show in my profile **accounts**.

**UPDATE:** The account creation procedure even asked me Google verification for allowing access to this site, so I did not login with open id is sure. But still it is showing open id.