# Please use a more obviously synthesized username for new accounts on http://data.stackexchange.com/ 

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, user-accounts, login

**Original problem**

I' ve opened http://data.stackexchange.com first time (from iPad 2 safary ), then clicked "log in", then clicked "log in with google" icon,
Then I've confirmed  that I am allow google to share my details with stackoverflow site( I don't remember exact wording).
And suddenly I was logged in With the name "jon.doe8598"

When I am opening https://data.stackexchange.com/users/8597/jon-doe8598 page, I see my photo and ability to edit/change profile.
Initially I was worried that it' s a security issue and I've logged in as another user,
but it seems, that user account was populate with the random default name instead of my real name. I also could not see associated accounts from other stackexchange sites.

I understand, tha I can change name the name, but I will not do it now, which could help investigation of the issue

It looked like a bug.

The community pointed me to other questions that were raised about the same issue:

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why am I jon.doe when logging into Data Explorer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85265/why-am-i-jon-doe-when-logging-into-data-explorer)
> [Wrong user when logging into Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95486/wrong-user-when-logging-into-data-explorer)

**Change request**

according to answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95531/163139, by design
A new account is assigned a unique predefined 'jon.doe' name).

The existing default is not obvious and misleading.
Can default name be changed to some more obvious like "Unknown user" or "specify name"?

Having non-English background, only after receiving this unexpected name, I found in Wikipedia the special use of Jon.doe name.

Also it will be good, if for a new user of Data Explorer an explanation will be shown as a message, something like what was answered at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95531/163139

> Data Explorer's login mechanism is not linked to the Stack Exchange
> Network. you get assigned a separate user
> account, which cannot be associated like a user account on the Network
> can be.
>
> If you want your displayed information on Data Explorer to match your
> other profiles, you have to manually copy in the info.

Comment: Data Explorer does not participate in the Stack Exchange network authentication scheme, so your profile there is separate from the one you use for the rest of the sites. As a result, we can't pull your name and associated profile information automatically.

Answer (score 6):

> Can default name be changed to some more obvious like "Unknown user" or "specify name"?

I don't see any problem with changing it to "user####", to be consistent with how the rest of the network works. I think that should be straightforward enough. I'll check to see if there are any objections, and if not I'll make the change.

On top of that though, it's probably also worth looking into whether or not the account creation process can be improved. Though Data Explorer definitely cannot participate in the network authentication scheme, it may be able to do a better job of figuring out who you are when you have an account on the network. I'll make a note to see what, if anything, can be done there.

Comment: Is any progress with this change? I've seen a new Jon.doe user created today.

Comment: I'll check, I'm not sure if I made this change or not. If I did, it hasn't been deployed yet, and if I didn't I'll try to fit it in tonight.