# SEDE signup should be clearer

Tags: feature-request, login, data-explorer, user-accounts

[The FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq) says the SEDE login isn't like other SE sites. When you try to signup/login, you will see you have a different profile. Many users are `jon.doe####`, but my account was `Laurel.Last.Name`, where "Last.Name" is my last name (with the space replaced by a `.`).

There should be a message right when you sign up that explains that SEDE accounts aren't really linked with your main account. It's confusing that the information currently is hidden away.

Comment: Where should it be clearer? At the login page where is asked for your OpenID? Or on your SEDE profile, after login? Somewhere else?

Comment: @rene I was thinking at the step where you link your account by clicking one of the options.

Comment: So on this [page](http://i.stack.imgur.com/A70B8.png), right?

Comment: @rene Yes. Currently, it's indistinguishable from the normal SE logins

Comment: Related or even dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146382/please-use-a-more-obviously-synthesized-username-for-new-accounts-on-http-data.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's related, but I'm not asking that we change what username is picked. I just want a clearer message that it's not linked.