# Google OpenId provided autologging me as another (possibly dummy) user

Tags: support, data-explorer, user-accounts

I wanted to find the posts eligible for archaeologist badge and came across the following link

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/77565/which-posts-are-eligible-for-archaeologist-edits-wip

I clicked on the Login link and was shown a page as below

[image]

After clicking the Google Open Id provided, I was automatically logged in as the user
**jon.doe11019**  instead of being prompted for my Google credentials or automatically picking my credentials that I had already used as seen in the above image.

[image]

**OS     :** Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.
**Browser:** Firefox 20.0.1

Comment: Did you use same Gmail account (in Data Explorer) which have you added in your login?

Comment: It auto-logged me into the following account ' jon.doe11019'. I did not see any page to enter my credentials.

Comment: Closely related: [Why merging accounts is not possible in Data Explorer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160143/187824)

Comment: I would have preferred it if I was auto-logged in as Romulus or at least be prompted to enter my credentials? Can anyone else reproduce this?

Comment: @Romulus Please see the links in the comments above.

Comment: @hims056: I always log in with just one Google account and no other way.

Comment: As well as [Wrong user when logging into data explorer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95486/wrong-user-when-logging-into-data-explorer)

Comment: I think as mentioned by Bart the problem is  "Data Explorer's login mechanism is not linked to the Stack Exchange Network, because Data Explorer is open-source and the Network site code is not."

Comment: Should I delete the question?

Comment: @Romulus - Nope. Duplicate question should be closed not deleted (if the question is well described).