# Different Usernames on stackexchange.com and data.stackexchange.com.. Is it a Bug?

Tags: support, bug, data-explorer, user-accounts, help

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why am I jon.doe when logging into Data Explorer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85265/why-am-i-jon-doe-when-logging-into-data-explorer)

Okay, The problem is when I log into stackexcange network and its network websites, My username is **Alphamale**. Which is correct. Following is the screenshot:

[image]

But i happened to go to https://data.stackexchange.com/, I logged in and on the top bar it was showing my username as **john.doe7809**..!! Why So? Is it a bug or default behavior??
Screenshot:

[image]

Any Ideas..??